# Central ASP.NET Identity Solution to all my intranet Apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I need some help with ASP.NET Identity.
All my Intranet Apps uses Windows Authentication. I want to create a unique central ASP.NET Identity Solution to all of them. Inside this solution I want to give for each user custom Roles and Claims that provide authorization for each App in Intranet.
I'm passing the User.Identity.Name from the Index of my Apps to this central solution.
The issue is that I have no idea how to get the claims and roles from my database and retrieve the information to the App the client is accessing.

If anyone could help...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [Identity Server](https://github.com/identityserver)

[There is a walkthrough for setting up what you're looking for here](http://blog.rogue-code.org/identity-server-3-plus-windows-authentication)

[Identity Server 3 docs](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/)

[Identity Server 4 docs (.Net Core)](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/)

Comment: This was marked down, probably because "use a different product" is a hard answer to hear.  But I really think it is the right one.  Identity server was designed with this scenario in mind. ASP.NET Identity was not designed with the same intents.

Comment: Thank you so much, thats exactly what I was looking for.